# Programmatically resizing/aligning loading view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

Ok, I'm adding a loading screen to UITableViewController just like in the YouTube, AppStore or iTunes apps. And I'm doing it like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:[[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]];
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    //load data
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview]; 
        //reload data graphicaly
    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

And `LoadingView` is a subclass of `UIView` that has a white background a spinner (`UIActivityIndicatorView`) and a label: "*Loading…*". Now I want to place this two thing in the center and make them somewhat "rock solid", so when you init that View on `viewDidLoad` and then it's *superview* resizes due to the presence of *navigation bar* and *tab bar* everything stays nicely centered. Oh and I want it to handle the rotation… etc.

Now here is how I've tried to do it:

```
#define LABEL_WIDTH 80

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        UIActivityIndicatorView* spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                     0,
                                                                     spinner.frame.size.width + 5 + LABEL_WIDTH,
                                                                     spinner.frame.size.height)];
        innerView.center = self.center;
        CGRect transitionFrame = spinner.frame;
        transitionFrame.origin.x = innerView.frame.origin.x;
        transitionFrame.origin.y = innerView.frame.origin.y;
        spinner.frame = transitionFrame;
        transitionFrame.origin.x = transitionFrame.origin.x+5+spinner.frame.size.width;
        transitionFrame.size.width = LABEL_WIDTH;
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:transitionFrame];
        label.text = @"Loading…";
        [innerView addSubview: spinner];
        [spinner startAnimating];
        [innerView addSubview: label];
        innerView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
        [self addSubview:innerView];
        self.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    }
    return self;
}
```

So the label and the spinner are set as subviews of some other view and that view is centered in our `LoadingView` and has all struts and springs unset, so after resizing it should stay in the middle. And `LoadingView` has all struts and springs set so it will change size together with it's *superview*…

But it all isn't working as intended, and I feel like I'm on the bad path and my code is wrong. Can someone help me a bit and explain what I should take a look at?

Comment: as you try to do the thing which can be done easily using [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/MBProgressHUD) code

Comment: @AalokParikh but that stuff places a semi-transparent square on the top of the view. And I want to make it like in Apple apps: [screenshot](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--CIU2PdpMfM/T5QyTKD0JDI/AAAAAAAABn8/DNULJX7FZcs/s320/iphone-ipod-loading-genius-playlist.png). But thanks, maybe I'll find a solution for my problem by looking at that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that

```
innerView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
```

was bad idea to center inner views.

I solved it by redefining `layoutSubviews` method.

The code itself can be found at https://github.com/Uko/UILoadingView/blob/master/UILoadingView.m